# Getting Write-Verbose messages output to show up in PowerShell module script code

Tags: powershell

I made a powershell module with Plaster. I have functions with Write verbose. Those work great. e.g:

```
function Get-Foo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([string])]
    param()
    Write-Verbose "Writing foo"
    "foo"
}
Get-Foo -Verbose
VERBOSE: Writing foo
foo
```

However, I have some startup code with Write-Verbose that does not get printed to the screen when I do `Import-Module -Verbose -Force`

```
[string] $TenantId = $null

try {
    $tenantInfo = Get-AzureADTenantDetail
    $TenantId = $tenantInfo.ObjectId
    Write-Verbose "Found existing connection AzureAd connection to tenant $($TenantId) ($($tenantInfo.DisplayName))"
} catch  [Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AadNeedAuthenticationException] {
    Write-Verbose "No Existing Azure Ad connection found"
}

>Import-Module .\Foo.psd1 -Verbose -Force
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Users\zippy\Source\Repos\psfoo\Foo.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Removing the imported "Get-AccessToken" function.
VERBOSE: Loading 'Assembly' from path 'C:\Users\zippy\Source\Repos\psfoo\Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary'.
VERBOSE: Loading 'Assembly' from path 'C:\Users\zippy\Source\Repos\psfoo\Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Users\zippy\Source\Repos\psfoo\Foo.psm1'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Get-AccessToken'.
```

I have even tried adding `[CmdletBinding()]param()` to the top of the psm1, which doesn't break my script, but doesn't make the verbose messages visible either.

Answer (score 0):

So somewhere in the mix the Import-Module is changing the VerbosePreference on you. If you do something like this you should see your messages.

```
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
Write-Verbose "Your Verbose Messages Here"
$VerbosePreference = "SilentlyContinue"
```

You could probably get away with setting it to Continue at the top, and Silence it at the bottom of your psm1 file.